# Closed formula for reversion of Jacobi theta series

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, theta-series

Considering the Jacobi theta: $\theta_3(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} q^{n^2}$,
we can invert $\theta_3-1$ in a small enough neighbourhood of 0.

Routine computation with Lagrange-Burmann inversion gives that the inverse have expansion
starting by:

$\frac{q}{2}-\frac{q^4}{16}+\frac{q^7}{32}-\frac{q^9}{512}-\frac{11 q^{10}}{512}+\frac{13 q^{12}}{4096}+ O(q^{13})$

Is there any known closed form (or recursive formula) giving the terms of this series?

(it is very closely related to OEIS A259938 suite: https://oeis.org/A259938, corresponding to $\theta_3(q/2)$ but which doesn't seem very studied as well)

Comment: By closely related, one should understand related by the substitution $q \mapsto q/2$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's exactly the same problem.

Comment: Morse-Feshbach (see [bottom of page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)) gives a sum over partitions of $n-1$ into numbers one less than a square; it's not a closed form or an elegant recurrence, but if your concern is practical evaluation then it may be of interest.

Comment: With a bit of simplification, $$A_n = n2^{-n} \sum_{s,t,u,\ldots} (-1)^{s+t+u+\cdots} \binom{n-1+s+t+u+\cdots}{s,t,u,\ldots}$$ where the sum is over non-negative integer solutions to $s + 2t + 3u + \cdots = n-1$.

Comment: To avoid confusion it would be better to call it reversion rather than inversion (the latter can be more likely understood as multiplicative inverse).

Comment: Apologies, I seem to have lost a reciprocal along the way. Change $n2^{-n}$ to $n^{-1} 2^{-n}$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, oh dear, I have made a mess of that comment. I copied the wrong part of my workings out: it should read $3s + 8t + 15u + 24v + \cdots = n-1$.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Indeed, I was about to make the same correction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, the form given by [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) cannot be much simplified here. It expresses the $n$-th coefficient of a series reversion as the sum of $n-1$ values of exponential Bell polynomials.

From the practical perspective, since $\theta_3-1$ contains nonzero coefficients only at square powers, computation of the $n$-th reversion coefficient amounts to iterating over the partitions of $n-1$ into squares $>1$ decreased by $1$ (almost [OEIS A243148](https://oeis.org/A243148) if we fix a number of squares). This yields the formula that Peter Taylor gave in the comments (modulo the corrections) for $n>1$:

$$A_n = \frac{1}{n!2^n} \sum_{(2^2-1)j_2 + (3^2-1)j_3 + \dots = n-1} (-1)^{j_2+j_3+\dots}\cdot \frac{(n-1+j_2+j_3+\dots)!}{j_2!j_3!\dots}.$$

Comment: Seems indeed to be the best we can do. I'll accept it as an answer to the question, thanks !